# Removing duplicates from string array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm new to C#, have looked at numerous posts but am still confused.

I have a array list:

```
List<Array> moves = new List<Array>();
```

I'm adding moves to it using the following:

```
string[] newmove = { piece, axis.ToString(), direction.ToString() };
moves.Add(newmove);
```

And now I wish to remove duplicates using the following:

```
moves = moves.Distinct();
```

However it's not letting me do it. I get this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Help please? I'd be so grateful.

Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has two errors. The first is the missing call to `ToList`, as already pointed out. The second is subtle. `Unique` compares objects by identity, but your duplicate list items have are different array instances.

There are multiple solutions for that problem.

- Use a custom equality comparer in `moves.Distinct().ToList()`. No further changes necessary.

  Sample implementation:

  ```
  class ArrayEqualityComparer<T> : EqualityComparer<T> {
      public override bool Equals(T[] x, T[] y) {
          if ( x == null ) return y == null;
          else if ( y == null ) return false;
          return x.SequenceEquals(y);
      }
      public override int GetHashCode(T[] obj) {
          if ( obj == null) return 0;
          return obj.Aggregate(0, (hash, x) => hash ^ x.GetHashCode());
      }
  }
  ```

  Filtering for unique items:

  ```
  moves = moves.Distinct(new ArrayEqualityComparer<string>()).ToList();
  ```
- Use Tuple`<string,string,string>` instead of `string[]`. Tuple offers built-in structural equality and comparison. This variant might make your code cluttered because of the long type name.

  Instantiation:

  ```
  List<Tuple<string, string, string>> moves = 
      new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
  ```

  Adding new moves:

  ```
  Tuple<string, string, string> newmove = 
      Tuple.Create(piece, axis.ToString(), direction.ToString()); 
  moves.Add(newmove);
  ```

  Filtering for unique items:

  ```
  moves = moves.Distinct().ToList();
  ```
- Use a custom class to hold your three values. I'd actually recommend this variant, because it makes all your code dealing with moves much more readable.

  Sample implementation:

  ```
  class Move {

      public Move(string piece, string axis, string direction) {
          Piece = piece;
          Axis = axis;
          Direction = direction;
      }

      string Piece { get; private set; }
      string Axis { get; private set; }
      string Direction { get; private set; }

      public override Equals(object obj) {
          Move other = obj as Move;
          if ( other != null ) 
              return Piece == other.Piece && 
                     Axis == other.Axis && 
                     Direction == other.Direction;
          return false;
      }

      public override GetHashCode() {
          return Piece.GetHashCode() ^ 
                 Axis.GetHashCode() ^ 
                 Direction.GetHashCode();
      }

      // TODO: override ToString() as well
  }
  ```

  Instantiation:

  ```
  List<Move> moves = new List<Move>();
  ```

  Adding new moves:

  ```
  Move newmove = new Move(piece, axis.ToString(), direction.ToString()); 
  moves.Add(newmove);
  ```

  Filtering for unique items:

  ```
  moves = moves.Distinct().ToList();
  ```

Comment: That's really helpful. Many thanks! will go for the class as advised. Thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call `.ToList()` after the `.Distinct` method as it returns `IEnumerable<T>`. I would also recommend you using a strongly typed `List<string[]>` instead of `List<Array>`:

```
List<string[]> moves = new List<string[]>();
string[] newmove = { piece, axis.ToString(), direction.ToString() };
moves.Add(newmove);
moves.Add(newmove);

moves = moves.Distinct().ToList();
// At this stage moves.Count = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, changed to the strongly typed List<string[]>. Unfortunately it's not removing duplicates at all, even though I no longer get the error message.

Comment: @Steve G, maybe because there aren't duplicates? When I tested this code with hardcoded values, inserted twice the same array, the Distinct method removed the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error is because you need to convert the result to a list:

```
moves = moves.Distinct().ToList();
```

However it probably won't work as you want, because arrays don't have `Equals` defined in the way that you are hoping (it compares the references of the array objects, not the values inside the array). Instead of using an array, create a class to hold your data and define `Equals` and `GetHashCode` to compare the values.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't do quite what I wanted it to. How is comparing the reference of the array objects useful? I'll try and do as you suggested and define Equals.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but this is an O(n) solution using O(1) additional space:

```
public static void RemoveDuplicates(string[] array)
    {
        int c = 0;
        int i = -1;

        for (int n = 1; n < array.Length; n++)
        {
            if (array[c] == array[n])
            {
                if (i == -1)
                {
                    i = n;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (i == -1)
                {
                    c++;
                }
                else
                {
                    array[i] = array[n];
                    c++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```